# Open subgroup and group algebra

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and $H$ be an open subgroup of $G$. Consider the group algebras $L^1(G)$ and $L^1(H)$ with convolution product and consider $L^1(H)$ as a subalgebra of $L^1(G)$ (i.e., $L^1(H)=\{f\in L^1(G): f|_{G\setminus H}=0\}$). Prove that $L^1(H)$ is closed subalgebra of $L^1(G)$.

Comment: I think I have seen it in "Introduction to banach algebras, operators, and harmonic analysis". Check it!

Comment: There is nothing there! I checked it.

Comment: The canonical embedding $L^1(H) \to L^1(G)$ is an isometry, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know! Could you please describe? Where I need being open for $H$?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a Haar measure on $G$, then the restriction $\mu_H$ of $\mu$ to subsets of $H$ is a Haar measure on $H$. If for a function $f\colon H \to \mathbb{C}$ we denote the trivial extension to $G$ by $\tilde{f}$, we have $$\lVert f\rVert_{L^1(H)} = \int_H \lvert f(x)\rvert\,d\mu_H(x) = \int_G \lvert \tilde{f}(x)\rvert\,d\mu(x) = \lVert\tilde{f}\rVert_{L^1(G)}.$$

Comment: Wow! great! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Choose $f\in\overline{L^1(H)}\subset L^1(G)$. There exists a sequence $\{f_n\}_n\subset L^1(H)$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(G)$. We know from real analysis this concludes there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_k$ of  $\{f_n\}_n$ such that $f_{n_k}\to f$ almost every where. Hence except a set, of measure zero for all $x$ $f_{n_k}(x)\to f(x)$. But we know $f_{n_k}(x)=0$ when $x\in G\setminus H$ and so $f=0$ almost every where on $G\setminus H$ which means $f\in L^1(H)$.

Comment: Good answer if you tell me where did you use openness of $H$!